# Ngnix setup for dedicated subdomains

Tags: nginx, dns

I want Ngnix to handle only a few subdomains and if it is not matching it should return an 404.

The following subdomains should work: domain.com, www.domain.com, api.domain.com and ftp.domain.com.

I use the following config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name *.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com api.domain.com ftp.domain.com;
    .....
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

The problem is that the website keeps working on every subdomain like test.domain.com. Of casurse the DNS is setup with an wildcard and I don't want to change that.

With adding the default_server I'm getting ssl errors?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need a catch-all server block to respond to requests to unknown domains. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) and the `default_server` option.

Comment: I have added the default config as described in the documentation but now SSL errors are generated. See my updated post.

Comment: Your new `server` block does not have `ssl` enabled. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for more.

Comment: I have ssl installed and it works correct on the server block domain.com, it is where the .... in my config file. Only in the server block with default_server I don't have ssl configured as it only needs to return an 404. Only why is now my domain server block with working, looks like everything now goes to the default_server block.

Comment: You need to understand that an HTTPS server must **first** negotiate an SSL connection **before** it can return a 404 response code.

Comment: I understand but for the non existing subdomain just an 404 needs to be generated without ssl